# How to select the lowest number per group in R

Tags: r

```r
rn=c(3,4,5,2,1,5,6,8,10,3,4,5,6,8,9,7)
na=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","CD","CD","CD","CD","CD","CD")
mo=c("ram","okd","mlu","lom","mpl","mpl","cdd","jjh","yyt","uu","tt","rre","llm","mm","mlp","lok")
dat=cbind(rn,na,mo)
```

I need to select for each group in na the lowest number in rn

example output:

```
    "1"  "A"  "mpl"
    "3"  "B"  "uu" 
    "4"  "CD" "tt"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are converting `rn` to strings? Your code creates a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`, so everything in this case is a string. For that, "lowest number" means something different (to R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `slice_min` after grouping (assuming 'dat' is `data.frame` and not a `matrix`) - `cbind` by default returns a `matrix`, instead use `data.frame` directly

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(na) %>%
  slice_min(n = 1, order_by = rn) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     rn na    mo   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     mpl  
2     3 B     uu   
3     4 CD    tt
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(rn, na, mo)
```

Answer (score 2):

`base R` option:

```r
rn=c(3,4,5,2,1,5,6,8,10,3,4,5,6,8,9,7)
na=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","CD","CD","CD","CD","CD","CD")
mo=c("ram","okd","mlu","lom","mpl","mpl","cdd","jjh","yyt","uu","tt","rre","llm","mm","mlp","lok")
dat=data.frame(rn,na,mo)

dat[dat$rn==ave(dat$rn, dat$na, FUN=min),]
#>    rn na  mo
#> 5   1  A mpl
#> 10  3  B  uu
#> 11  4 CD  tt
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Base `R` solution:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split.data.frame(dat, dat$na), function(x) x[which.min(x$rn),]))
   rn na  mo
A   1  A mpl
B   3  B  uu
CD  4 CD  tt
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this even with a simple `filter` after creating the `data.frame`

**Data**

```
dat=data.frame(rn,na,mo)
```

**Procedure**

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(na) %>%
  filter(rn==min(rn)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     rn na    mo   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     mpl  
2     3 B     uu   
3     4 CD    tt
```